# Composite English words with “like” (basin-like, heaven-like, etc.)

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs

How would I say “with basin-like characteristics” in French?

I have something along the lines of “*avec des caractéristiques comme un bassin*” but I find it very ugly and unappealing. Anything better?

Some context:

> With nearly 10 km of uninterrupted flatwater, consistent depth and *basin-like characteristics*, as well as some of the most placid and beautiful flatwater in the world, the canal is a wonderful place to host an event.

Comment: In oral speech with people I'm familiar with (and who understand English), I tend to keep the “*machin-like*” form in French, for concision. Good question !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### English

Some suffixes in English are derived from its Germanic base.
 **-like** is one of those suffixes (German: **-lich**, Dutch: **-lijk**)

Words of this nature do not translate easily into French.

---

### French

French co-incidentally possess no such affix that performs a similar process as *-like* does in English. Therefore utterances containing such constructions in English must be altered in French much like how you already translated *… with basin-like characteristics*.

**Examples:**

1. with childlike characteristics → *avec des caractéristiques enfantines*
2. with soldier-like poise → *avec un maintien soldatesque*
3. with ball-like shape → *avec la forme d'une balle*

**Explanation**

If the word has an appropriate adjective form, then use that. Otherwise use example 3 to formulate the translation.

Additionally, using a construction “*avec le [qualified characteristic]*” only feels right to me as an adverbial prepositional phrase.

Comment: Thanks for the nice breakdown. I'll edit my post to add some context.

Answer (score 6):

If the noun has an corresponding adjective in French, chances are that it will suit your needs best. *Un lieu paradisiaque* is a heaven-like place.

Otherwise, I belive “*qui ressemble à [un bassin]*” is the most lightweight general approach.

In the specific context you gave, I'd go for “*aux allures de bassin*”.

Comment: Oh, I like "aux allures" and I think it fits quite well. Thanks

Comment: "aux allures de bassin" absolutely expresses exactly what the sentence in English says. This means in English something along the lines of "... with the captivating qualities of a basin". It simply implies that these qualities are generally positive ... and alluring :).